# After submit need thank page to scroll to top in FB tab

Tags: facebook, scroll

I am working in `ShortStack`, makes custom FB tabs/pages. I searched like crazy, I saw tons of answers but none that address a non-traditional iframe. I didn't create the iframe, `Shortstack` did. I put my webform code in. After submit, does not go to top of next page.

Any suggestions as to type of code I could use? Shortstack support will not help since it is custom code I am putting in.

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
```

You can use this to scroll to the top, just place it inside a code widget in the shortstack designer.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/

Example:

```
$('#promotion').bind('success.form', function(event) {          
   FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```